# Javascript - Math Function For 1 Day Calendar

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working on some Javascript for a Ruby on Rails project, but my knowledge is light in the Javascript world.

We have a calendar you can select dates from, ideally we want 1 day to be calculated like this:

Car hire price per day = £100

How we want it to work:

Hire for 1 day (i.e. pick up morning 08/02/15 - drop off evening 08/02/15) = £100

At the moment the Javascript is calculating a a day as over a 24 hour period (i.e. 08/02/15 - 09/02/15), which we don't want.

The code:

```
var hire_from = null;
    var hire_to = null;

    var setPrice = function () {
        var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
        if (hire_from && hire_to) {
            var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((hire_from - hire_to)/(oneDay)));
            var price = diffDays*$("#enquiry_price").val();
            $("span#weekly_price").html("&pound; "+price.toFixed(0))
            var fee = price*$("#enquiry_discount").val()
            $("span#commission").html(fee.toFixed(0));
        }
    }
```

How can I change the Javascript to work as previously described?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Whatever you have written is not giving u the answer

Comment: @MukeshAgarwal what do you mean? Thanks

Comment: Please provide more examples to know what is needed. If taken at 23:59 and returned at 00:01 does it count as a day or two?

Comment: In the 6th code line there is `hire_from - hire_to`. Shouldn't it be the other way around? It would remove the need for Math.abs()

Comment: @Hurelu Apologies! Yes you are correct if the car was returned 00:01 that is 2 days, since the hire has spanned across two dates.

Answer (score 0):

The way the question is formulated, 2 possible formulas are likely:

**A:** The first minute counts as one day and the second billable day starts at 24 hours + 1 minute. This is closer to the presented code. 
(ie. fractional days rounded up)

```
oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
days = Math.ceil( ( hire_to - hire_from ) / oneDay );
```

**B:** the number of days is the difference in calendar days +1, regardless of the time. In line with the clarification.
(ie. inDate-outDate+1)

```
//convert a ms time stamp to a local time day stamp
//ie. whole days since long ago
function localDayStamp(ms) {
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
    date = new Date();

    //remove all fractional miliseconds from the local day stamp
    date.setTime(ms);
    date.setHours(0);
    date.setMinutes(0);
    date.setSeconds(0);
    date.setMilliseconds(0);

    return Math.ceil(date.getTime()/oneDay);
}

// get the days
days = 1 + localDayStamp(hire_to) - localDayStamp(hire_from);
```

Comment: The hire would not be on time so much, I may have put a little too much emphasis on this. It's days, so if you picked on the From calendar 08/02/15 and also 08/02/15 for the To calendar, this would be classed as a full one day booking. If From was 08/02/15 and the To calendar was 09/02/15, this would be classed as a 2 day booking (i.e. price * 2)